# How can I make z to 26?

Tags: c, ascii

I want to make A to 1, ... , Z to 26.
My code can make A to 1, but it can't make J -> 10 , ... , Z -> 26. Please tell me how to change mine.

```
void changeToDigitEncode(char s[], char e[]) {
    int i;
    int eIndex = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        e[eIndex] = s[i]-'A'+'0'+1;
        eIndex++;
    }
    e[eIndex] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char sentence[20], encoded[40];

    scanf("%s", sentence);
    changeToDigitEncode(sentence, encoded);
    printf("%s\n", encoded);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic behind `'A'+'0'+1`?

Comment: You are doing ASCII arithmetics dealing with single characters. You cannot store 10 in a single character. Please show your input, output and what you expect as output .

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but maybe this comes close: `sprintf(&e[2*eIndex], "%02d", s[i]-'A'+1);`

Comment: The encoded string is in the range 1 to 26, so mostly not printable characters.

Comment: You cannot put `10` (or `26`) into a single char; you need two chars.

Comment: my expectation: AZ to 126

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can do this:

```
int a_lower = 'a' - 'a' + 1; // value : 1
int j_lower = 'j' - 'a' + 1; // value : 10
```

For capitals, a similar thing:

```
int a_upper = 'A' - 'A' + 1; // value : 1
int j_upper = 'J' - 'A' + 1; // value : 10
```

Answer (score 1):

As a comment pointed out, You can't store most integers as a single character. Whereas a character array element is a single character. So, instead you will have to create an integer array and store the values there.

Plus, it would be `s[i]-'A'+ 1` simply

Another thing I added is a termination condition for the `encoded` array which would be number 0 as no alphabet will give number 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeToDigitEncode(char s[], int e[]) {
    int i;
    int eIndex = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        e[eIndex] = s[i]-'A'+1;
        eIndex++;
    }
    e[eIndex] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char sentence[20]; 
    int encoded[20];

    scanf("%s", sentence);
    changeToDigitEncode(sentence, encoded);
    
    for(int i=0; encoded[i]!=0; i++) {
        printf("%d ",encoded[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code consider ip[] as your s[] and op[] as your e[]

```
char ip[] = "ABC";
    char op[3];
    char temp[50];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
while(ip[i]!='\0')
{
    int num=ip[i];
    num-=64;

    sprintf(temp, "%d", num);
    k=0;
    while(temp[k]!='\0')
    {
        op[j++]=temp[k++];
        
    }

    i++;
}
op[i]='\0';
printf("-->%s\n",op);
```

this will only work for String in Caps

Comment: this will convert AZ to 126